# Python Lambda File Sorting/Restriction

Tags: python, file, sorting, lambda

I and reading in a directory of files and I'm trying to filter out files based on if a string exists in the file name or not, so I have two file name types:

- till_20200810150309.gz
- flod_20200810150310.gz

The below code snippet reads in the files ok, but I'm trying to only limit it to `till` files, it's currently returning all files found in the directory and not filtering out just the `till` ones.

```
files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(root_directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_directory, f)) and f.endswith('.gz')], key=lambda x: x if "till" in x else "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using more or less the same strategy you can add a third condition:

```
files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(root_directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_directory, f)) and f.endswith('.gz') and f.startswith("till")])
```

That will limit the files to only those starting with till.

You also don't need to setup a key to sort since you want it done based on the file name.